# Complete SQL before return from constructor

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I am using pg-promise:

```
class Test{
    constructor(){
        this.a = db.any('SELECT * FROM test');
    }
}
```

If I call `test.a`, it will return `Promise { <pending> } }`.

How do I handle this problem? I cannot use `.then()` to solve this problem, because I hope the value can be stored in `this.a` before return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @CertainPerformance this one might be a little different, because `await` cannot be used in a `constructor`

Comment: @Neverever Indeed, the response should come back before actually instantiating the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a variable, foo, that is initialized as empty, then have the promise success function set the value of foo to the asynchronous result.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use .then() to solve this problem, because I hope the value can be stored in this.a before return.

This is a contradictory statement. If you need the value inside the constructor, you have to use `then`. Otherwise, you can use `then` later, like this:

```
var t = new Test();
t.a.then(data => {});
```

or

```
const t = new Test();
const data = await t.a;
```